# RVM ruby 1.9.2 Symbol not found: _STR2CSTR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

Troubleshooting RVM.

Installed both Ruby 1.9.2-Head / 1.9.2-p136

When running the server, server crashes receiving this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _STR2CSTR
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _STR2CSTR
Expected in: flat namespace
```

Found this posting but didn't help much:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/215406

Any solutions would be great!

Comment: What OS? How did you install RVM?

Comment: Mac OSX version 10.6.6

Installed RVM using 

$ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )

Comment: I also might want to add that I added this to my batch_profile

    [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Comment: I'm getting this same problem but coming from the raspell gem.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem with Ruby 1.9.2 and the sqlite-ruby-1.2.4 gem, which is somehow required by Rails 3.0.3. This was my error message:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _STR2CSTR
  Referenced from: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite3_api.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace
```

And I was able to fix it by going to `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/ext` where the source code for the sqlite3_api.bundle was located, and replacing every occurrence of `STR2CSTR` by `StringValuePtr` [as described here (first reply)](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/215406). I then recompiled (using make) and copied the resulting `sqlite3_api.bundle` to the lib/ folder.

Answer (score 3):

I updated my sqlite3-ruby gem to sqlite3
Just change (in your Gemfile)

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

to

```
gem 'sqlite3', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your gems (ncurses?) uses the native C API.
The function STR2CSTR was removed in Ruby 1.9
So either you use the ffi-ncurses gem or you may
Patch the source of the ncurses gem and recompile it.

Comment: still seem to have the same problem...these are the steps that i took.

1.) rvm default - uses ruby 1.9.2
2.) rvm use @rails3 - named gemset
3.) cd testapp - testapp dir
4.) gem install ffi-ncurses
5.) bundle install
6.) Ran the server...

Still have the same problem